# How to filter in firebase by an inner attribute?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Given I have the following schema:

```
{
  houses:  {
    { house1: { is_empty: true }, house2: { is_empty: false } }
  }
}
```

How can I get all the houses which `is_empty` is true?

Comment: Same as for your other question: what language are you using? Did you try anything already? Firebase has pretty good documentation (for [web](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html), [ios](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/retrieving-data.html) and [android](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/retrieving-data.html)) that contains the answer for this and many other question.

Comment: I am using JS, I have tried dividing my set so I have house/empties and house/not_empties.

Comment: I am not sure how can I use the `orderByChild` in this scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JavaScript you can get all the houses that are empty with:

```
ref.child('houses').orderByChild('is_empty').equalTo(true);
```

Be sure to add the following index to the security rules of your Firebase dashboard:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "houses": {
      ".indexOn": ["is_empty"]
    }
  }
}
```

Please take some time to study the [Firebase guide for JavaScript](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/), specifically the [section on querying](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-complex-queries). It covers this and many more topics.